# What different type of code should I use to decode this string?

Tags: encryption

Just saw this string of letters:

[picture](https://preview.redd.it/vnhfi6ogmp051.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=4ab4af741f217d2025eba336c8f2b3c97e3c03b8)

here's a raw text version:

```
bgedrf,jeidiqghe
gq-gfdchcubfe--q
iqhogmebhbiehc
ticdcf

x

geheedajftc,dieieff
hggyiddifeetshdccf
cdxhd-hcvddhie-cgi
efgfih-rlixeffeii-hd
feigfg
```

someone has already tried a Caesar Cipher, but I'm not exactly an expert on encryption and cryptography.

wondering if y'all might be able to recognise any significance. There could be numbers involved (because of the "x" which i would assume means "times".